# Using only one loop to generate nested arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to generate a nested array of consecutive numbers using only one loop. I feel it should be solved somehow using remainder operator but can't quite come up with a general solution. Anyone has any suggestion or hints?

input: 4 
output: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4

Comment: Why not just use nested loop ? Simple and easy to understand

Comment: I guess it's more a math problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the modulo operator (`%`), but note that you should loop from zero and up, and the result from modulo is also from zero and up, so you have to add one to it.

```js
var input = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < input * input; i++) {
  var n = (i % input) + 1;
  
  document.write(n + '<br>');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
int input = ...
int i = 0;

while(i<=(input*input)){
    int output = (i % input) + 1;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This is very elegant, but my next thought is that it is not quite as intuitive as a nested array would be.

Comment: @Ludovic, I certainly understand that ... just throwing in the random thoughts I'm having after being up all night.